# Recovering Mysql - how to get a dumpfile from wampserver and none running db

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump

I had the following: 
- Wampserver/mysql/drupal + batch file with auto backup by use of mysqldump.
- Backup was distributed off and online.

then : my laptop was stolen :-( and I need to recover but... the size of the backup is zero bites aahhhhh. I have a good mysqldump until 20/09/2014

In need to have a mysqldump until 19/12/2014 and this is still available in database in the wampfolder. I needed to re-install wamp so I have two folders now:

d:\wamp with the new wampserver
d:\wamp_old with the old wampserver with the database until 19/12/2104.

How to get a dumpfile from the none running db?

Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit lost in your explanation, but there may not be much of a problem.

- You have a dump from December?
- But it is in the 'wrong' directory?
- The dump was taken using mysqldump?

Reloading is nothing more than
mysql -uroot -p

Comment: Sorry for the explanation. I'm not native English :-) I have a complete non working setup of mysql under wamp including db from december. So including the data folder. 
How to get this DB (which I assume is in the data folder) to a Mysql dump file?

Comment: If you have the entire data folder, then (1) install Wamp; (2) stop mysql; (3) replace the new Wamp data folder with the saved folder; (4) start mysql.  This is likely to "just work".

Comment: This worked like a charm. thxs